# Unable to open the MudDrawer from NavMenu in blazor application

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I am designing a windows-style notification drawer that open up when the user clicks on the button with **MudBlazor**. I am using MudDrawer that has a list of items, however so i am able so far to open the drawer when a user clicks on page **BUT** my requirement **is to open up the drawer(MudDrawer) when a user clicks on an item on NavMenu**.
Here is what i have tried :

```
<MudPaper Width="250px" Elevation="0" Class="py-3">
    <MudNavMenu Bordered="true">
        <MudNavLink Href="/dashboard">Dashboard</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/reminders" >Reminders</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/about">About</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavMenu>
</MudPaper>
```

and the Reminders razor component code looks like this:

```
@page "/reminders"
<div class="d-flex">
    <MudButton Color="Color.Inherit" OnClick="@ToggleDrawer" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.TwoTone.Schedule" Class="mx-2">Show notifications</MudButton>
</div>
<MudDrawerContainer Class="mud-height-full">
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@open" Width="450px" Fixed="true" Elevation="24" Variant="@DrawerVariant.Temporary"
               DisableOverlay="false" Style="background-color:whitesmoke;position:fixed;" Anchor="Anchor.End">
        <MudDrawerHeader>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">List of Reminders</MudText>
        </MudDrawerHeader>
        @foreach(var reminder in ReminderList)
        {
            <MudCard>
                <MudCardHeader>
                    <CardHeaderContent>
                        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">@reminder</MudText>
                        <MudText Typo="Typo.caption">@DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd hh:mm tt")</MudText>
                    </CardHeaderContent>
                    <CardHeaderActions>
                        <MudTooltip Text="Delete">
                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Close" Color="Color.Default" />
                        </MudTooltip>
                        <MudTooltip Text="Settings">
                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Settings" Color="Color.Default"/>
                        </MudTooltip>
                    </CardHeaderActions>
                </MudCardHeader>
            </MudCard>
            <MudDivider />
        }
        
    </MudDrawer>
</MudDrawerContainer>

@code {
     public List<string> ReminderList {get; set;} = new List<string>
     {
         "Reminder 1",
         "Reminder 2",
         "Reminder 3"
     };

     public bool open = false;

     public void ToggleDrawer()
     {
        open = !open;
     }
}
```

The way this works is that the user clicks on the menu 'Reminders' then the reminders page is open and on the reminder there is button 'Show notifications' that open up the drawer.
What i want is just to click on the menu 'Reminders' and then the drawer is opened up.

The working demo can be found [here](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYGHueuBLrqNXFCy)
I appreciate any help.

Comment: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mawdkoPRYDWLgTje

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Brian. I totally forgot that i can add the 'OnClick' event callback on the the NavLink. The only problem i have is that i want the Drawer to be in a separate component. Currently in my real application the Drawer is on the same page as the NavMenu and when i click on the link the drawer is not showing properly on the page.

Comment: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GaGROoFfobqKvwzm

Comment: This is what exactly I wanted! Thank you so much Brian you made my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MudDrawer` is a responsive component. That means that the initial value for `MudDrawer.Open` depends on the window/screen size. You're accessing that property here `@bind-Open="@open"`. And setting the initial value for it as false here `public bool open = false;`

So here's two ways you can solve your problem.

1. Set the initial value of `open` to true `public bool open = true;`, then the drawer will open only when the window size is big enough. (You can try this by increasing the display window size on *try.mudblazor* ).
2. If you want the drawer to open even if the window size is not big enough then you can override the `OnParametersSetAsync()` like below.

```
public bool open;
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(()=>{open = true; });
}
```

[snippet for 2nd option](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOGHOIFxHMXQdMRE)

Comment: The second solution works well. I am asking myself why you chose to use 'OnParametersSetAsync()'? Thank you so much for your time and feedback, i really appreciate.

Comment: We want the open value to be set to true **after** the `MudDrawer` component sets the value to false. Which happens during its first render on OnAfterRenderAsync. But we can't set it on `Reminders.razor`'s first render because that happens before that. So we set it after first render and before final render of the lifecycle which happens during `OnParametersSetAsync`.

Comment: Okay, I now get it. Thank you so much for your time and feedback